Android Chrome no longer displaying special symbols from font
If I'm trying to use a symbol like ⮜ in a web page, Android Chrome doesn't render it.
It used to be that I could work around this by including a font like Symbola, and then setting the element containing that symbol to use the custom font.
eg:
@import 'https://fontlibrary.org/face/symbola';

p {
    font-family: 'SymbolaRegular';
}

At some point over the last few months, this stopped working.
Example CodePen: https://codepen.io/mt_xing/pen/BaeLgxY
On Windows, this still works fine:

And it used to work on Android too. However, I noticed that recently, this no longer works on my Pixel phone:

What has changed recently, and has anyone figured out how to make these special characters show up on Android again apart from just making them images?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Have you tried other Android phones, like Samsung?

In fact the font can't be loaded. On windows the font is replaced with a default symbol font (in my case Segoe UI Symbol). Quite likely fontlibrary.org has changed directory structures. So you should report this as a bug. You may also host the downloaded ttf locally

The actual ttf is still accessible, though it downloads very slow
